# jQuery Mobile split button clickEvent no ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a list of elements that have split buttons. Each split button got an id. If I catch the click event from the clicked split button, it has no id.

**Split Button:**

[image]

```
 <li><a href="#" id=<%=mId%> class="mainButton">
    <img src="../../_assets/img/album-hc.jpg">
    <h2>Warning</h2>
    <p>Hot Chip</p></a>
    <a id=<%=myId%> href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="splitButton"></a>
</li>
```

In Backbone I listen to the click-event of the class splitButton.
The event is fired correct, but it's event-object doesnt have an id:

**Backbone:**

```
event:
{
    "click .mainButton" : "mainButtonClick",
    "click .splitButton": "splitButtonClick"
},

splitButtonClick: function (event)
{
    alert(event.target.id); //id is empty ("")
}
```

Comment: Are you binding any event to the parent anchor?

Comment: the parent Button also is listened by a click-listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
splitButtonClick: function(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is giving me the contextId, not the button id.

Comment: ok. when you check the id in the browser, is it showing correctly?

Comment: can you print the output of e.target and e.currentTarget if possible

Comment: Hold on, now it works with currentTarget. I must have done sth. wrong before. The first test gave me the id of the triggerd element. But now i reveive the split button id ... great :)